# C++ Do I need to write throw clause for a function everywhere?

Tags: c++, exception, declaration

### Before

Consider to have a class and a global function:

This is, for example, `usefulfuncts.hpp`

```
void dosome(int a, int b) throw (std::exception);
```

This is `usefulfuncts.cpp`

```
void dosome(int a, int b) throw (std::exception) {
   //...
}
```

And this is aclass.hpp

```
class aclass {
   // Members...
   friend void dosome(int a, int b) throw (std::exception);
   // Members...
};
```

### After (what I would like that to be)

Ok! I would like to understand if it is strictly necessary to write everytime the `throw` clause. So for example can I do this?

This is `usefulfuncts.hpp`

```
void dosome(int a, int b) throw (std::exception);
```

This is `usefulfuncts.cpp`

```
void dosome(int a, int b) { /* OMITTING IT! */
   //...
}
```

And this is aclass.hpp

```
class aclass {
   // Members...
   friend void dosome(int a, int b); /* OMITTING IT */
   // Members...
};
```

Is this right? To put it only in the main declaration? Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Omitting a exception specification means that your function can throw ***any*** exception.

Exceptions specifications are bad. There are hardly any compilers which implement the feature correctly. They have been deprecated since the C++11 Standard. In fact Exception specifications were considered a failed experiment even while they were a part of the C++03 standard.

**Good Read:**
[A Pragmatic Look at Exception Specifications](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill22.htm)

Comment: Yeah but if I specify it just once, that it throws one exception and in other contexts, not to be redoundant, I do not specify it... what happens???

Comment: Use them. Just don't specify them.

Comment: @Andry: The answers here are specifically talking of *"Exception Specifications"* not *"Exceptions"*.You should use exceptions. There are some instances where they are the best means(failing constructors).Please read the linked article from Herb it will give you a good idea of why exception specifications are considered evil.

Comment: @Andry you should use exceptions, just not exception specifications.

Comment: OK wua, didn't realize it at all... thanks guys... I'll check correct later as i cannot before seven mins... I gotta go now, I'll check your answer later bye :)

Answer (score 3):

Declaring exceptions is a bad idea. From http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill22.htm :

> Moral #1: Never write an exception specification.
>   Moral #2: Except possibly an empty one, but if I were you I’d avoid even that.

Answer (score 1):

[Exception specifications are deprecated in C++11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++11#Features_removed_or_deprecated) - do not write exception specifications unless it is to specify that your function is guaranteed *not* to throw an exception.

Note that actually providing this guarantee is harder than it may seem - Herb Sutter has written [many articles](http://gotw.ca/gotw/020.htm) and [a book](http://gotw.ca/publications/xc++.htm) on the subject of exceptions and exception safety.